# Better alternative to gradient descent

Tags: gradient-descent

Is there any method that is faster and more efficient than gradient descent for updating weights in a neural network. Can we use multiplicative weight update in place of gradient-descent. Is it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [LMA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm). I've heard that MLPs are most efficiently trained with it.

Another promising algorithm is [BFGS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher-Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm).

Both algorithms are based on [Newton's method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to approximate functions. And in my opinion harder to understand than Backpropagation.